# mongodb order of AND clauses

Tags: mongodb

When running AND query on mongodb, is there any performance effect to the order of the clauses?
My tests seem to indicate 'no', but I wonder whether I'm missing something because I saw articles claiming the contrary.

E.g. consider some 'Blog' documents:

```
{_id:1, type:'personal',   author:'Mr A',  ...}
{_id:2, type:'commercial', author:'Mr A',  ...}
{_id:3, type:'personal',   author:'Mr B',  ...}
{_id:4, type:'commercial', author:'Mr B',  ...}
{_id:5, type:'personal',   author:'Mr C',  ...}
{_id:6, type:'commercial', author:'Mr C',  ...}
{_id:7, type:'personal'  , author:'Mr D',  ...}
{_id:8, type:'commercial', author:'Mr D',  ...}

With indexes:
   col.ensureIndex({type:1})
   col.ensureIndex({author:1})
```

Now I can run AND queries with different ordering:

```
col.find({type:'commercial', author:'Mr A'})
col.find({author:'Mr A' , type:'commercial' })
```

I tried running 'explain' and got the impression it would take the 'author' index regardless of order (because "Mr A" only has two blogs, while "commercial" appears in 4 blogs). So is it a documented feature to select the "most narrowing" index, regardless of clause order?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a compound index if you query for more than one field.

`db.col.ensureIndex( { "type": 1, "author": 1 } )`

Lookup the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/

> **The order of the fields in a compound index is very important.** In the
>   previous example, the index will contain references to documents
>   sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of
>   the item field, sorted by values of the stock field. See Sort Order
>   for more information.

Comment: Of course you're correct, I naturally referred to cases of intentionally separate indexes (serving other queries as well). Sorry for not clarifying, and thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

> So is it a documented feature to select the "most narrowing" index,
>   regardless of clause order?

Yes, MongoDB will always try to use the index that will give you the best results. When you do a query MongoDB uses query optimizer:

> The MongoDB query optimizer processes queries and chooses the most
>   efficient query plan for a query given the available indexes. The
>   query system then uses this query plan each time the query runs.

When you run a query without a [query plan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/), MongoDB will create a new one. To create a query plan, MongoDB will run multiple queries in parallel for multiple candidate indexes. The selected index will be then used in all subsequent queries with the same query pattern.

You can read more details about [query plans](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) in the MongoDB docs.

Also, just for your reference, if know what index you want to use with your query, you can specify one with a [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) cursor method.

```
col.find({type:'commercial', author:'Mr A'}).hint({ author : 1});
```

> When running AND query on mongodb, is there any performance effect to
>   the order of the clauses?

With two separate indexes on both fields order doesn't matter, because MongoDB will always select the best index.